# Are there any other works featuring Riddick?

Tags: riddick-franchise

I particularly enjoyed the Riddick movies. Do you know any more works featuring the hero, or at the very least in that particular universe?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

So far there are 4 **movies** (Which I presume you've seen):

- [Pitch Black](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0134847/)
- [The Chronicles of Riddick: Dark Fury](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0407658/) (animated movie, acting as a bridged between the two 'live' acted films)
- [The Chronicles of Riddick](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0296572/)
- [Riddick](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1411250/)

There's talk about possible sequels. ([Sequels](http://moviesblog.mtv.com/2008/08/25/vin-diesel-promises-two-more-riddick-sequels/))

There are also two animated short films and a motion comic:

- [Into Pitch Black](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0366620/) (Acting as an intro to Pitch Black)
- [Slam City](http://www.pitchblack.com/blackbox/slamcity.html) (Considered to be not-entirely-canon, but available for free on the website)
- [Riddick: Blindsided](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Riddick_(franchise)#Riddick:_Blindsided_.282013.29) (2013 motion comic bridge between films 2 and 3.)

---

**Books**:

- [Pitch Black](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0312970889) (A novelisation based on the movie)
- [The Chronicles of Riddick](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0345468392) (A novelisation based on the movie)
  The books offer a lot more detail on the characters and some of the events that occurred.

---

Other than that there are two video **games** ,two online free games and a game for Android :

*Online:*

- <strike>[The Hunt for Riddick](http://www.thechroniclesofriddick.com/hunt/hunt.php?chap=1)</strike> (broken link,  archive [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120206012253/http://www.thechroniclesofriddick.com/hunt/hunt.php?chap=1)) (internet game)
- Escape From Crematoria (Fan game, couldn't locate this)

*Video Games:*

- [The Chronicles of Riddick: Escape From Butcher Bay](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Riddick:_Escape_from_Butcher_Bay)
- [The Chronicles of Riddick: Assault on Dark Athena](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Chronicles_of_Riddick:_Assault_on_Dark_Athena)

*Android:*

- [Riddick: The Merc Files](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gamingcorps.riddick&hl=en)

Comment: The two tCoR games listed above are both FANTASTIC. They are easy candidates for "best movie games" primarily because Vin is a huge part of the studio that made them.

Comment: To elaborate on the above: Escape from Butcher Bay begins with a prison sociology simulation - whereby you acquire your shank - and is followed by a rampage through the sewers to gain your eye-shine - and is dotted with stealthy shiv-fests through a gauntlet of everything DOOM 3 should have been.

Comment: And Dark Athena is everything from the above only with more memorable characters, a longer play time, boss battles with mechs that are later pilot-able, and one of the most satisfying end boss battles in an FPS ever. Mainly because you have to be like Riddick to solve it.

Comment: According to IMDb, the Riddick sequel 'The Chronicles of Riddick: Dead Man Stalking' is currently in post-production and is slated for release in 2013.

Comment: A new film "Riddick" was released in 2013.

Comment: there's one more game with riddick in it where they're playing a game with a disc.it's on the xbox. can't remember the name. I just know he's on the convict team.

Answer (score 0):

Vin has said that there will be another movie. He envisioned the movies to be like Lord of the Rings and Pitch Black as his Hobbit. The last movie is supposedly going to take us to Furyia and the Omniverse.